# How to apply wait for an element using WinAppDriver on UWP in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, automation, appium, winappdriver

I am working on automation of UWP app using WinAppDriver with C# but at some points my tests are failing as some elements take time to appear and I couldn't apply waitDriverWait (guess WAD doesnt have this) so I found below code which is working but would like to know if there is any better approach please?

```
 public static void WaitForElement(this WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> driver, string IDType, string elementName, int time = 10000)
    {
        var wait = new DefaultWait<WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>>(BasePage.WindowsDriver)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time),
            PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
        };

        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(InvalidOperationException));

        wait.Until(driver1 =>
        {
            int elementCount = 0;
            switch (IDType)
            {
                case "id":
                    elementCount = driver1.FindElementsByAccessibilityId(elementName).Count;
                    break;
                case "xpath":
                    elementCount = driver1.FindElementsByXPath(elementName).Count;
                    break;
                case "name":
                    elementCount = driver1.FindElementsByName(elementName).Count;
                    break;
            }
            return elementCount > 0;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `WebDriverWait` successfully with my WinAppDriver automation in the past -- you will have to install the `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` to access the `ExpectedConditions` class as it is now obsolete in the standard Selenium namespace, but I don't see anything stopping you from using `WebDriverWait`.

Waiting for element Text to be populated with a value:

```
var Driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>();
var myElement = Driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("someId");

var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(myElement, "text"));
```

Waiting for an element to be displayed:

```
var Driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>();
var myElement = Driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("someId");

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(d => myElement.Displayed);
```

Waiting for an element to exist, using another approach with `FindElements` and `By.Name`:

```
var Driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>();

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(d => d.FindElements(By.Name("someName")).Count > 0);
```

As mentioned, I have used these exact methods for waiting in the past with `WinAppDriver`, with success. Please let me know what issues you encounter with these approaches.

Comment: Hi Christine, thanks for your very helpful response - I've tried:

var myElement = Driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("someId");
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(d => myElement.Displayed);

However I encounter an exception immediately on the first line "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters" i.e. it fails to store that element because it doesn't exist...

Does this approach still work for you? I've raised a few queries around this on StackOverflow - but nobody responds. Is this broken in WinAppDriver currently possibly?

Comment: If the first line is failing when you invoke `Driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId`, the most likely issue is the UI element does not match the selector you are using to locate it. Because I cannot see the UI you are working on, you could inspect the element in Accessibility Insights (or whatever inspection program you use) and post its inspection properties in your original question.